# Data types, values and objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm getting pretty confused about this data type thing, especially with objects.

I read that a data type is basically an attribute for information/data used in our programs that tell the interpreter what operations can be done with that information without causing errors. Hence, every piece of information has an associated data type.

JS has 7 primitive data types and the data type Object.

Now, suppose that I write:

```
let person = {
   name: "John",
   age: 39,
};
```

Every article I found on the web says that person is a variable that store an object.

That's what gets me confused.What I'm asking is, wouldn't be more correct to say that "person is a variable that refers to a value whose data type is Object"?

I'm sure this is just overthinking the topic, however I want to get the correct basics of programming before moving on.

Comment: "that stores" and "refers to" seem interchangeable to me. Although I am likely wrong

Comment: Person is a variable of the data type object, so although the sentence you found in articles is technically correct, it sounds like weird English to me. (keep in mind a lot of us aren't native speakers) The person object has two properties: `name` with the data type string and `age` with the data type number.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are way overthinking it for now... Without much talking about typing, because there's much more to it than just Object. Also know that in Javascript, every value is an object, or almost.

What's good to figure out though, as you mentioned: person is a variable that refers to a value.

This is important, that makes all this more obvious:

```
let person = {name:"John",age:39};
let john = person;
john.age++; // Increase john's age by 1.
console.log(person.age); // 40
```

As you can see, person and john both refer to the same object. Untill I put another reference on them:

```
let person = {name:"John",age:39};
let john = person;
john.age++; // Increase john's age by 1.
console.log(person.age); // 40
person = {name:"Mary",age:34};
console.log(john.name) // John
```

Here, we replace the reference on person. john remains the same. Now both variable have "diverged" from each other.

Comment: Is the sentence:
"person and john both refer to the same object" correct?

Isn't object a data type, not a value?

Comment: Hard to say... Because for what it's worth, data type is simply inexistent in Javascript. Everything is basically an object. So in this sentence, they refer to the same value. That value being of type Object... It's like IRL, you can call it a car, a bus, a boat... They are all vehicules, but in the end they are all Objects also... Or tengible things.

As soon as you'll stop wondering about types, everything is gonna get clearer. As, again, javascript does not have types. For types to be meaningful you'd use Typescript, but then it would just be sugar coating above typeless Javascript .